# How to let 'cp' command don't fire an error when source file does not exist?

Tags: shell, copy

I'm using Mac OS X.
I'm trying to copying some files with cp command for a build script like this.

```
cp ./src/*/*.h ./aaa
```

But this command fires an error if there is no .h file in ./src directory.
How to make the command don't fire the error? (silent failure) The error makes build result fail, but I just want to copy when only there are some header file.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

If you're talking about the error message, you can suppress that by sending it to the bit bucket:

```
cp ./src/*/*.h ./aaa 2>/dev/null
```

If you want to suppress the exit code and the error message:

```
cp ./src/*/*.h ./aaa 2>/dev/null || :
```

Comment: It would be nice to explain what `:` means in this context.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost: In Bash and some other shells the colon is a null utility (no-op). It's [specified](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#colon) by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/). Since it always returns true, it's used here to suppress the exit code of a failed `cp` (should that be desired). The shell builtin `true` could be used instead and would be more readable.

Comment: More about `:` – [What Is the Purpose of the `:' (colon) GNU Bash Builtin?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3224878/95735)

Comment: This will also ignore other errors (source/destination directory doesn't exist, source file exists but is not readable, disk full, read-only filesystem, IO error, `cp` not being in `PATH` somehow...)

Comment: syntax error near unexpected token `||'

Comment: @thang: What shell are you using?

Comment: ubuntu's default bash.  i guess linux bash is different from mac os bash.

Comment: @thang: All versions of Bash at least as far back as version 2 (_ancient_) support `||` regardless of operating system. What does `false || echo "OR"` output for you?

Comment: || seems to work in shell but doesn't when i put into shell script.  i think that's the culprit

Comment: @thang: How are you running your script? `bash ./scriptname` for example? Or with a shebang like `#!/bin/bash`? Or do you have stray characters in your script such as Windows/DOS line endings `\r\n`?

Comment: #!/bin/bash  everything is linux, so nothing windows.

Comment: @thang: Well without seeing the actual line there's nothing else I can suggest.

Comment: thanks for your help.  i did a work around with if [-f ...] before doing cp.  probably not the most elegant but it works and it's a shell script so elegance isn't so important.

Answer (score 25):

You're looking for something along the lines of

```
if [ -e file ]
 then cp file /somewhere
fi
```

(Unfortunately, the `-f` option is not the droid you're looking for.)

If you want to match a glob, that won't work; use `find` instead, e.g.:

```
find ./src -name \*.h -exec cp {} ./destination \;
```

Comment: Note that there is a potential TOCTOU issue with such an approach (e.g. if you use `set -e`, and the file disappears between the `[` and the `cp` invocations, your script will crash).

Comment: You could explain why use `-e` instead of `-f` and what is the difference.

Answer (score 16):

Piping the result to true ensures that the command will always succeed. I have tried this on Linux but not on any Mac OS:

```
cp ./src/*/*.h ./aaa | true
```

Comment: The simple pipe `|` is always run while `||` is only done in case of an error. And `true` is usually a binary while the colon `:` is a builtin and doesn't consume a PID.

Comment: A bash script on MacOS - Yosemite containing "cp ./src/*/*.h ./aaa" command does not error out if the .h files do not exist.

Comment: Simple, readable, and working. This is exactly what I needed, thanks mate.

Answer (score 13):

Old question, but might still be relevant for others.
If you don't *need* to use cp, you could try with rsync.
To copy all files from a source to a destination directory, run:

```
rsync -avzh --ignore-errors /path/to/source /path/to/destination
```

Rsync comes with most Unix-like systems such as Linux, Mac OS X or FreeBSD.

Comment: You could use rsync instead of cp, adding the parameter `--ignore-missing-args`: `rsync -av --ignore-missing-args ./src/*/*.h ./aaa` This has the advantage over `--ignore-errors` that the only errors ignored are those related to source files not existing. With `--ignore-errors` every error is ignored, which may be dangerous. Also, take into account that this parameter is fairly recent, so it might not be present in old versions of rsync.

Comment: what if the source directory doesn't exist?

Comment: I don't think that should be the responsibility of rsync to be honest. Rather, you can check upfront if the source directory exists, e.g. `[ -d /path/to/source ] && rsync -avzh --ignore-errors /path/to/source /path/to/destination`

Answer (score 2):

You could force the correct error status. With a function:

```
$ cpalways () { cp $1 $2 2>/dev/null ; return 0 ; }
```

Given the following:

```
$ ls foo bar baz
ls: baz: No such file or directory
bar foo
```

Regular copy will return an error. It will return an exit status of 1.

```
$ cp baz bar ; echo $?
cp: baz: No such file or directory
1
```

If we use the cpalways() function above, any errors will be hidden:

```
$ cpalways baz bar ; echo $?
0
$ cpalways foo bar ; echo $?
0
$ cpalways baz bar ; echo $?
0
```

Answer (score -1):

This works

`$(cp ./src/*/*.h ./aaa | true)`